# What is going wrong when I try to solve a simple linear equation?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to understand how does the `LinearSolve` function works. I'm trying it out like this:

```
A'
```

> `{{2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 0}}`

```
A' . {-2, 3, 1}
```

> `{0, 0, 0}`

```
LinearSolve[A', {0, 0, 0}]
```

> `{0, 0, 0} (* <- Here I'd like to have {-2, 3, 1} *)`

As the answer I was expecting to get `{-2, 3, 1}`, but I got `{0, 0, 0}` instead. Could someone explain to me why it works like this?

Comment: In _Mathematica_, it is `Transpose[A]`, not `A'` as in _Matlab_. Moreover, you might want to have a look at `Nullspace`.

Comment: Additionally to what Henrik wrote, you can use a shorthand notation to get the postfix operator form of `Transpose` by entering `Escape tr Escape`, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html) under Examples->Basic Examples. This has a very similar look as the MATLAB version.

Comment: See the documentation. "For underdetermined systems, `LinearSolve` will return one of the possible solutions." `{0,0,0}` is a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relavant mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is true, that `{-2, 3, 1}` is a solution of `a.{x, y, z} == {0, 0, 0}`, it is only one of an infinite number of solutions. `{0, 0, 0` is also a solution and therefore, a valid result. To get the set of solutions for your system use `Reduce`.

```
a = {{2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 3}, {3, 2, 0}};
sol = Reduce[a.{x, y, z} == {0, 0, 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

> `y == -((3 x)/2) && z == -(x/2)`

```
sol /. x -> 0
```

> `y == 0 && z == 0`

```
sol /. x -> -2
```

> `y == 3 && z == 1`